# Magento 1 : Admin Panel Not Saving Changes In Theme?

Tags: admin, magento-1, theme, backend

Working On Magento 1.9 Website active on scala hosting.

I am using porto theme, all was going good but all of sudden am not able to save the changes done on theme . when l click on 'save config' it gets saved but changes are not done. on other modules and extensions am able to save the changes.

can anyone please guide the about the issue and how can l solve the same.

Comment: have you checkd Magento/Server logs?

Comment: yes i checked in var/log but nothing is there.

Comment: Thanks for helping sir, I contacted to hosting team and they solved the issue saying that it was due to some mod_security factor which is solved 

Comment: Yes, maximum time server security stop functionality, happy to hear that your problem resolve!!!

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your kind gesture. I appreciate your help & guidance.